# Promise response - Angular 2/5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-promise

I have a promise that returns an array of marker, but when I want to assign the response in a variable, I get an error.

**This is the method to get the marker array**

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {

    load(currentOptions: Array<Option>): Promise<Array<Marker>> {
        return new Promise<Array<Marker>>(onResolve => {
          let currentMarkers = new Array<Marker>();
          ...
          ...
          onResolve(currentMarkers);
        });
    }

}
```

**From another ".ts" I try to get the data like this**

```
markerList: Array<Marker> = new Array<Marker>();


ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.MyService.load(OptionsArray).then(x => {
        this.markerList = x;
    })
}
```

Sorry for the error in Spanish. The translation would be something like this:
**The type "Marker []" can not be assigned to the type "Marker []". There are two different types with this name, but they are not related**

[image]

Comment: I fixed it, it was a conflict because I have classes with the same name.